# How does one render different text-content depending on a button-element's click-event triggered toggle-state?

Tags: javascript, event-handling, state, togglebutton

I have a button which when clicked, changes the text from 'Report A Problem' to 'Close' & opens a dropdown text input,  When the button is clicked again it remains set to 'Close', whereas I would like it to return to 'Report A Problem'. I only know how to trigger 2 events with one click, whereas this would be a two-click action. Any ideas of the best way to approach this?

```js
function change() {
  document.getElementById("myBtnToReportABug").innerHTML = "Close";
}
```

```html
<button id="myBtnToReportABug" onclick="change()" type="button" class="btn btn-secondary float-right" data-toggle="myModal" data-target="#myModal"> Report A Problem </button>
```

Comment: A button like component which toggles text can be achieved without JavaScript via css generated content and `data-*` attributes of a checkbox, thus being not depended on client-side libs for localization (l10n) / internationalization (i18n).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The biggest advantage of the following approach is that internationalization and localization does not depend on client side JavaScript rendering.

Since a checkbox is perfectly suited for representing a toggling state, such state depended toggle text just needs to be rendered into two `data-*` attributes of a `checkbox` control, which together with an outer `label` element mimics the behavior of a toggling button.

All one needs is just HTML and CSS.

And making the client side script, which is responsible for opening and closing a modal, run on this small component shouldn't be a problem at all ...

```css
[data-modal-checkbox-button] {
  /* appearance: button; */
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  min-width: 1em;
  padding: 4px;
  text-align: center;
  white-space: nowrap;
  background: #ccc;
  border: 2px solid;
  border-radius: 4px;
  border-style: outset;
}
[data-modal-checkbox-button]:active {
  border-style: inset;
}
[data-modal-checkbox-button] > [type="checkbox"]:focus {
  outline-offset: 8px;
  outline-color: darkorange;
}
[data-modal-checkbox-button]:active > [type="checkbox"] {
  left: -1px;
  top: -1px;  
}

[data-modal-checkbox-button] > [type="checkbox"] {
  appearance: none;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
}
[data-modal-checkbox-button] > [type="checkbox"]::after {
  content: attr(data-checked-false);
}
[data-modal-checkbox-button] > [type="checkbox"]:checked::after {
  content: attr(data-checked-true);
}
```

```html
<label data-modal-checkbox-button>
  <input
    name="report-a-bug"

    type="checkbox"
    class="btn btn-secondary"

    data-toggle="myModal"
    data-target="#myModal"

    data-checked-true="Close"
    data-checked-false="Report A Problem"
  />
</label><br/>

<label data-modal-checkbox-button>
  <input
    name="report-a-bug"

    type="checkbox"
    class="btn btn-secondary"

    data-toggle="myModal"
    data-target="#myModal"

    data-checked-true="Schließen"
    data-checked-false="Ein Problem melden"
  />
</label><br/>

<label data-modal-checkbox-button>
  <input
    name="report-a-bug"

    type="checkbox"
    class="btn btn-secondary"

    data-toggle="myModal"
    data-target="#myModal"

    data-checked-true="закрывание"
    data-checked-false="Сообщить о проблеме"
  />
</label>
```

In case the OP has to rely on a scripting approach, the OP might consider the following generic and language independent solution ...

```js
function toggleModalButtonState({ currentTarget }) {
  const { dataset } = currentTarget;
  const { textClose, textReport } = dataset;

  const state = (dataset.state === 'close')
    ? 'report'
    : 'close';
    
  dataset.state = state;

  currentTarget.textContent = ({
    report: textReport,
    close: textClose,
  })[state];
}
document
  .querySelector('#myBtnToReportABug')
  .addEventListener('click', toggleModalButtonState);
```

```html
<button
  id="myBtnToReportABug"

  type="button"
  class="btn btn-secondary float-right"

  data-toggle="myModal"
  data-target="#myModal"

  data-state="report"
  data-text-close="Close"
  data-text-report="Report A Problem"

>Report A Problem</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

I would use another data attribute to track a toggle state, ex with `data-button-state` as a new attribute:

```js
function change() {
    var button = document.getElementById("myBtnToReportABug");
    var buttonState = button.dataset.buttonState;
    var buttonText;
    var buttonState;

    if (buttonState === 'report') {
        buttonText = "Close";
        buttonState = "close";
    } else {
        buttonText = "Report A Problem";
        buttonState = "report"
    }

    button.innerHTML = buttonText;
    button.dataset.buttonState = buttonState;
}
```

```html
<button
    id="myBtnToReportABug"
    onclick="change()"
    type="button"
    class="btn btn-secondary float-right"
    data-toggle="myModal"
    data-target="#myModal"
    data-button-state="report"
>
        Report A Problem
</button>
```

With this approach you can have multiple states, and just define what you want to do with those states in each `if` statement :)

Comment: @cdln ... This is a viable implementation of a client side toggle script. You might consider this as the accepted answer.

Answer (score 0):

Just check the current value:

```
<button id="myBtnToReportABug" onclick="change()" type="button" class="btn btn-secondary float-right" data-toggle="myModal" data-target="#myModal"> Report A Problem </button>
function change() {
      var theButton = document.getElementById("myBtnToReportABug");
      if (theButton.innerHTML == "Close")
          theButton.innerHTML = "Report A Problem";
      else
          theButton.innerHTML = "Close";
}
```

Comment: @cdln ... 1/2 ... How can this get accepted/upvoted? This is by far the worst possible approach. Why do I make such a bold / not that polite statement. This script checks for a specific content. On top it uses `innerHTML` for rendering a `textContent`. **Really?**  What happens if due to the render process an additional leading or trailing whitespace is part of this text content? What about a typo due to a human mistake in the CMS. Even if you control all that, as soon as someone decides to change `Report A Problem` into `Report a problem` you manually need to adapt the script. ...

Comment: @cdln ... 2/2 ...And did I already mention i18n/l10n? A client side scripting solution needs to be based on a generic approach for managing the toggle state. One might choose a `data-*` attribute or maybe even a class-name (the latter I personally do not prefer since class names can change too).

Comment: You're right, it's very dirty.Thank you for the comment! That was very informative for me (but there are more polite ways to tell me that ;) )

Comment: I was not criticizing you but the OP for accepting this answer. In addition it was a critique to anyone who gave an upvote on this solution without critical thinking. Of cause it was a critique on the approach itself. It was polite enough in not  having mentioning you at all. I never attack people on a personal level.

Comment: @PeterSeliger While I appreciate and have learned from what you wrote, perhaps you would benefit from realising that not everyone is aware of best practice/way things are to be done. Therefore I see the code works, I accept it. Unless you believe StackOverflow is purely populated by people who already know the best answer to what they ask?

Comment: @cdln ... I'm also always learning and therefore I'm fare away from *"already know(ing) the best answer"*. Also, I was not expecting to deliver the accepted answer; more to receive both up- and downvotes due to people sometimes feel personally offended from getting criticized the technical base of their solution.

Answer (score 0):

I would use a [data attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Howto/Use_data_attributes) to maintain the state of the button.

You should also use [`addEventListener`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) instead of the onclick attribute.

```js
const report_btn = document.getElementById('myBtnToReportABug');

report_btn.addEventListener('click', function(){
  var btn_state = this.getAttribute('data-state');
  switch(btn_state){
    case "report":
    
      // The button is in the "report" state
      this.innerHTML = "Close";
    
      // Change the button state
      this.setAttribute('data-state', 'close')
      
      // do other stuff here...
      
      break;
    case "close":
    
      // The button is in the "close" state
      this.innerHTML = " Report A Problem ";
    
      // Change the button state
      this.setAttribute('data-state', 'report')
    
      // do other stuff here..
    
      break;
  }
});
```

```html
<button id="myBtnToReportABug" data-state='report' type="button" class="btn btn-secondary float-right" data-toggle="myModal" data-target="#myModal"> Report A Problem </button>
```

Comment: @cdln ... This too is a viable implementation of a client side toggle script.

Answer (score -1):

You just need to add a condition in your function that tests what the `textContent` is, and change it accordingly.

(Note: inline JS is generally frowned upon these days so I've used [`addEventListener`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) here.)

```js
// Cache the button element and add a listener to it
const button = document.getElementById('myBtnToReportABug');
button.addEventListener('click', handleClick, false);

function handleClick() {

  // Depending on the textContent of the button
  // switch between the two texts
  if (button.textContent === 'Close') {
    button.textContent = 'Report a problem';
  } else {
    button.textContent = 'Close';
  }
}
```

```html
<button id="myBtnToReportABug">Report A Problem</button>
```

Answer (score -2):

You mean the button needs to change STATE not event! The event is always the same... the onclick!

So you just need to cycle through a variable counter with every click, like this...

```
 if(State==3){State=1;} else {State ++;}
```

And then...

```
 if(State==1) {RunFunction1();} else 

  if(State==2) {RunFunction2();} else 

   if(State==3) {RunFunction3();}
```

Changing the button text would take place inside each numbered function above, as well as whatever else you intended to happen for each state.